# Как работают sprite sheet или как устроен background-image + background-position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Не знаю откуда пошли `sprite sheet`, но впервые о них услышал когда увлекся играми. В играх с ними все просто, есть большая картинка спрайт-лист, есть маленькая картинка, которую создаешь в ручную и копируешь в неё нужную часть из большой.
Но если верить информации из полученной из гугла, то будь у меня спрайт-лист с тысячью кадрами, то отобразив их при помощи `background-image` + `background-position` я создам исходное изображение (спрайт лист) тысячу раз.

Прав я?

Comment: Так загрузится оно один раз, потом из кеша будет браться.

Comment: ru_volt: но если спрайт состоит из 100 кадров и весит 1МБ, то памяти он отожрет 100МБ... Это же безумие. Получается что использование спрайтов в вэбе схоже с тем жалким зрелищем когда маленькая девочка криво красит губы маминой помадой и одевает её туфли на три ноги больше её...

Comment: Если вы 100 раз используете спрайт, это не значит что он в сотне разных мест в памяти хранится. Но да, в памяти будет храниться большая картинка, не маленький кусочек.

Comment: На практике ну не будет у вас спрайтшита из сотни мегабайтных иконок, не будет. Оверхед по памяти будет, но небольшой. А снижение сетевой нагрузки будет, и ощутимое.

Comment: Ну то есть это типичный способ пожертвовать одними ресурсами, ради экономии других ресурсов, ничего страшного я в этом не вижу. В крайних случаях, вроде гигантских спрайтов для отрисовки пары маленьких иконок, эти жертвы неоправданы. Но в общем не все так плохо. Представьте другую крайность, сотню запросов для того чтобы загрузить 100 25 килобайтных иконок.

Comment: @ru_volt именно это и значит что в памяти он создастся сто раз. иначе если бы я изменил, скажем цвет у исходного, то поменялось бы везде. А ведь Вы этого не хотите, Вы же не хотите при увеличении одной иконки увеличить все. Вот по этому исходный спрайт и будет копироваться в памяти каждый раз. Это если в html нет какой-то внутренней оптимизации. В общем понятно, спасибо.

Comment: оптимизации на уровне браузеров разумеется есть, их очень серьезные люди пишут и оптимизируют до чего руки дотягиваются)

Comment: @ru_volt оптимизации копирования изображения?

Comment: что конкретно делают браузеры для оптимизации спользования памяти спрайтами, я не знаю, признаюсь =) Но я как-то делал бенчи на реальном проекте, и потребление памяти росло нелинейно от количества иконок в спрайте. Будем надеятся тут появится кто-то кто объяснит лучше как оно рабоате. Через пару дней если никто не ответит полно, повешу баунти, мне тоже интересно

Comment: *Но если верить информации из полученной из гугла* -- приложите ссылочку на найденное, тут регулярно случаи, когда находки неверно истолковываются.

Comment: @Кнопкатык откройте любой хелп и почитайте что там написано, да и логически подумайте над этой темой. Что происходит когда Вы просите создать картинку? создается картинка! Если бы ссылка была всегда на одну картинку, то при изменении масштаба, цвета или поворота в одном любом месте, эти изменения бы затронули все. А если этого не происходит ответ один - разные экземпляры. И чего ту не верно трактовать..

Comment: @vas если их много, приложить любой из примеров не составит проблемы, а сейчас вы являетесь самостоятельным распространителем сомнительных слухов без указания их первоисточника.

Comment: Не понял про увеличение и изменение цвета. Где оно и при чём тут вообще спрайт?

Comment: @ Qwertiy ну Вы иконку выдернули из спрайта и повернули её. И если бы ссылка была на один участок памяти, то эта иконка повернулась бы во всех местах где её используют.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы исходите из предположения, что использование спрайта где-то на странице действительно требует копии куска спрайта в памяти. Это не совсем так.

Как работает отрисовка (по крайней мере в Windows, на пальцах):

- Под окно программы (браузера) выделяется большой прямоугольник в памяти видеокарты.
- По некоторым событиям часть этого прямоугольника помечается как "подлежащая перерисовке" - например

  - поверх окна программы кто-то протянул другим окном
  - программу развернули или свернули
  - сам код программы решил, что какой-то кусок окна устарел и его надо перерисовать - например, поменялся DOM в случае браузера
- Это вызывает событие перерисовки окна (или его части)
- Обработчик перерисовки решает как выглядит перерисовываемая часть, и заново рендерит ее в прямоугольник в памяти видеокарты.

Как при этом браузер обходится со спрайтами:

Если в момент перерисовки элемент, использующий спрайт, попал в перерисовываемую область - нужный кусок спрайта копируется в тот самый прямоугольник в видеопамяти. При отрисовке он поворачивается/масштабируется/обрезается под размер перерисовываемого элемента.

Копия спрайта при этом не создается (или создается временно) - прямогульник же выделен уже давно, и от отрисовки спрайта он больше не стал. Т.е. момент "создать картинку" из спрайта, которого вы так боитесь, не наступает - просто кусок спрайта копируется в уже выделенный буфер в памяти.

Comment: Я могу сказать следующее - Вы сейчас описали работу с gpu, но css это cpu. По этому я не могу с Вами поспорить.. Исходя из Ваших слов все расчеты ведутся в gpu и все является растром. Но блин, а что если спрайт векторный - svg? Вектор в видеокарте это же неправда..?

Comment: @vas я описал механизм отрисовки. не вижу, в каком месте я упомянул, что он должен происходить именно на уровне GPU. Или что "все является растром". Я написал что все *превращается в растр в процессе отрисовки*. Если спрайт - векторный svg - то при отрисовке он все равно станет куском растровой картинки в видеопамяти. Тектовый HTML - и тот превращается в растр видеопамяти - причем с применением того же самого механизма отрисовки. По той простой причине, что превратить что-то в растр в видеопамяти - это *единственный* способ показать что-то на экране.

Comment: @vas конкретно по вашему примеру с "повернуть и отрисовать" - в GDI это делается вызовами TranslateTransform + RotateTransform + DrawImage. При этом отрисовывается сразу повернутая и смещенная картинка, а оригинал - остается без изменений.

Comment: Я могу согласится что рендер именно так и происходит. А на остальное пока забью и поверю Вам.

Comment: Вот ещё что.. Я загрузил изображение в 100МБ и создал сто canvas в которые отрисовал сотую часть исходного изображения. Итого получается 100МБ. Это понятно. А вот теперь я создаю 100 canvas размером с само исходное изображение и накладываю на 99% маску. Будет ли при этом память так же как и в первый раз? Мне кажется что нет. Если Вы скажите что да, то я не поленюсь и ещё этот вопрос отдельно задам.

Comment: @vas, но ведь канвас - это не фон.

Comment: @Qwertiy что значит фон? автор ответа говорит что пофиг ведь все в итоге рисует видеокарта. Разве не это он пытался сказать в самом ответе и комментариях к нему?

Comment: @vas канвас - это не результат отрисовки. Это самостоятельный элемент. Вы создаете 100 канвасов - вы тратите на них память 100 раз. Вы отрисовываете один канвас 100 раз - вы не тратите на него память 100 раз. Отрисовка существующего элемента и создание нового - это два совершенно разных процесса. Из разных областей. Первый - это рендеринг. Второй - управление объектами в терминах DOM. Простая аналогия - вы нажмете F5 на странице 10 раз - комментарий будет занимать столько же места на экране. Вы запостите комментарий 10 раз - он займет в 10 раз больше.

Comment: @Qwertiy ведь автор говорит о том что  браузер рисует  windows и видео карта. Автор не говорит в контексте спрайта. И все что я пытаюсь сделать, это применить его слова к другим технологиям и если он окажется не прав, значит и ответ его будет уже не верным.

Comment: @PashaPash а `div` с сылкой на картинку это не самостоятельный элемент?

Comment: @PashaPash то есть я понимаю что `canvas` это лишь массив у которого элементы это значения цвета пикселей и именно это и увеличивает память. Но разве `div` устроен не так же? Разве он не копирует весь рисунок в себя так же как и `canvas`?

Comment: @vas естественно, не копирует. div это просто кусок DOM. Канвас позволяет рисовать на себе, и память он ест именно под хранение нарисованного. Т.е. в момент рендеринга содержимое канваса - картинка - копируется в видеопамять. А div на себе рисовать не позволяет. В момент рендеринга он просто отрисовывает свое содержимое (текст, вложенные элементы, *рамочки*) прямо в видеобуффер. Т.е. может браузер и кэширует результат прошлой отрисовки div, на случай если тот не поменялся (точнее, 100% кэширует), но он делает это только для отображаемых элементов. А не вообще для всех элементов в дереве.

Comment: @PashaPash Вы говорите что если я создам это сообщение десять раз то весь увеличится тоже в десять раз. А если я создам это сообщение десять раз, но девять из них закрою картинкой, то ведь вес так и останется в десять раз больше? Ведь не важно что видно, а что нет, сам факт того что текста в десять раз больше и он где-то хранится, а значит и занимает место тоже больше. Это верно?

Comment: @vas да, вес текста увеличится, примерно на количество байт, равное количеству символов * 2. Что вообще несоизмеримо с объемом памяти, который потребовался под хранение их в виде картинок.  Место в памяти под сами элементы div, естественно будет потрачено (под значения их аттрибутов). Но в виде картинок они при этом храниться не будут.  В случае со спрайтами - будет потрачено время на хранение факта, что спрайт привязан к конкретному диву + размер + смещение. Но при этом копия картинки - самого спрайта - создана не будет.